# A polynomial whose integral with higher powers of $x$ vanishes

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $7$ with real coefficients such that $p(π) = \sqrt{3}$ and $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^kp(x)dx = 0\ \  \text{for}\  0 \le k \le 6$$.
What are the values of $p(0)$ and $p(−π)$?

Does Riemann-Lebesgue lemma have any role to play here? Or the Weierstrass approximation theorem? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Only finite-dimensional linear algebra is needed.

Comment: @deyore you mean the rank nullity theorem? how do we exactly use it here?

Comment: The evaluation at $\pi$, and the integrals $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^k\times \cdot$ are all linear functionals on the space of polynomials of degree at most $7$. Express your polynomial in your favorite basis of that space, use the given values of those functionals to compute the coordinates of $p$ in that basis and then you have $p$ and you can answer all answerable questions about $p$, in particular its values at $x=0$ and $x=-\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let 
$$p(x)=a_7X^7+...+a_1x+a_0$$

Then 
$$p(\pi)=\sqrt{3} \\
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^kp(x)dx = 0\ \  \text{for}\  0 \le k \le 6$$

is a system of 8 equations with 8 unknowns. The solution can be made shorter by applying Gram-Smidt to $1,X,X^2,..,X^7$.

Comment: how do we apply gram-schmidt? the $x^k$ and $p(x)$ are orthogonal, but how can we exactly use to solve the system?

Comment: @vidyarthi Use GS on $1,X,X^2,..,X^6,X^7$ to create an orthogonal basis $f_0,f_1,.., f_7$. Write $$p(x)=a_0f_0+a_1f_1+...+a_7f_7$$Now, since $P(X)$ is orthogonal on $\mbox{Span}\{1,X,..,X_6 \}$ you get that $a_0=..=a_6=0$, so all you have to do is calculate $a_7$.

Answer (score 1):

As already remarked the problem boils down to the inversion of a $8\times 8$ matrix.
A more efficient approach comes from noticing that the rescaled [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) $R_n(x)=P_n(x/\pi)$ are orthogonal with respect to the standard inner product of $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$.
In particular a solution is clearly given by $p(x)=\sqrt{3}\,P_7(x/\pi)$, which can be efficiently computed from Rodrigues formula. In such a case $p(0)=0$ and $p(-\pi)=-\sqrt{3}$. It only remains to prove that the solution is unique.